# Displaying content from text editors in React App

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to make a simple blog with React and Laravel and I've used a text editor to insert the contents of blogs. Now when I try to display those blogs in my React App, it completely displays the content as string but not as html elements. Here's what I've done (code & screenshots):

**My Form**

[image: Laravel Blog Post Add Form]

**Laravel Controller**

```
public function save(Request $request) {

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'language' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    $post = new Posts;
    $post->language = $request->input('language');
    $post->body = htmlspecialchars($request->input('body'));
    $post->save();

    return redirect('dashboard');

}

public function posts($id) {
    $posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->select('id', htmlspecialchars_decode('body'))
    ->where([['language', '=', $id]])->get();
    return response()->json($posts); 
}
```

And here's what my view looks like: 
[image: React View Of Blog Content]

Can anyone please help what am I doing wrong here? Any help is very much appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `htmlspecialchars_decode` inside the select, you need to use it after you get the data and the best way is using [eloquent accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators):

```
//POSTS CLASS:

public function getBodyAttribute(){
  return htmlspecialchars_decode($this->body);
}

//----------------------

//CONTROLER CLASS:

public function posts($id) {
    $posts = Posts::select('id','body')
    ->where([['language', '=', $id]])->get();
    return response()->json($posts); 
}
```

P.S. its preferable to use singular names for models

Comment: Hi, thank you Anas, it does decode the content but it doesn't apply the styles on body. Now it spits out content like:  <p style="color: #000000">Blog Content</p>

Comment: How does the output look like?

Comment: Have you tried htmlspecialchars($request->input('body'),ENT_NOQUOTES)

Comment: Thank you @AnasBakro i did solve the issue. Your answer helped me to make my laravel code better and figured out that problem was in react side.

Comment: Welcome, could you post your solution in answers so others may benefit from it.